# Casting to generic subtypes of a generic class

Tags: java, generics, casting, subclass

Suppose I have this:

```
class Base<T> {}

class Derived<T> extends Base<T> {}
```

Then in my code, I can safely cast without a warning like this:

```
public <T> void foo(Base<T> base) {
    Derived<T> f = (Derived<T>) base; // fine, no warning
}
```

which is fine. But if the derived class has more type parameters, it doesn't work any more:

```
class Base<T> {}

class Derived<T, U> extends Base<T> {}

public <T> void foo(Base<T> base) {
    Derived<T, ?> f = (Derived<T, ?>) base; // unchecked warning!
}
```

Why is that? Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Comment: Why doesn't it work? It worked for me...

Comment: What "doesn't work" is that I get an unchecked warning although this cast is perfectly safe.

Comment: What compiler? I'm seeing it with the Eclipse compiler.

Comment: What Java version/IDE are you using? I don't get any unchecked warning with Java 6 u 37 and Intellij IDEA 12.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like a bug to me. From [JLS §5.5.2. Checked Casts and Unchecked Casts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.2):

> A cast from a type S to a parameterized type (§4.5) T is unchecked
>   unless at least one of the following conditions holds:
>
> - S <: T
> - All of the type arguments (§4.5.1) of T are unbounded wildcards
> - T <: S and S has no subtype X other than T where the type arguments of
>     X are not contained in the type arguments of T.

Given your types `Base<T>` and `Derived<T, ?>` as `S` and `T` respectively, the first two conditions clearly don't hold.

That leaves the third condition - which won't hold if we can identify a subtype of `Base<T>` other than `Derived<T, ?>` whose type arguments are not contained in the type arguments of `Derived<T, ?>`. If the warning is correct, such a subtype must exist, but I can't identify one. For example, `Derived<?, ?>` doesn't work because it isn't a subtype of `Base<T>`.

Comment: I was hesitant to post this answer because the Eclipse compiler has a good track record with generics, and seeing this warning in Eclipse makes me think I'm missing something. If I'm misreading the JLS, please comment or edit my answer for correctness.

Comment: JDK 7 does not issue the warning. JLS 5/6 did not mandate the warning. I think jdt compiler devs simply missed the change or ignored it due to the error (it should be: "... no Subtype X other than T where **|T|=|X| and** ..."

Comment: @BenSchulz Yeah, I was wondering about that wording myself - is there a JLS issue reported for that?

Comment: Not that I know of, but those are impossible to track down for such minor technicalities.